# Shortcut for subscript in PowerPoint

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

Is there a keyboard shortcut to format as subscript in PowerPoint 2011?  Most sources point to <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> but this zooms out.  Is there a way to customize these shortcuts, or more importantly to *discover* them without spending a lot of time googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your system keyboard shortcuts go to:

System Preference >Keyboard >Shortcuts

To apply subscript formatting (automatic spacing) in PowerPoint 2011

⌘+SHIFT+MINUS SIGN

To see all PowerPoint shortcuts [go here](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/powerpoint/item/13dfdf52-4ce3-4ec5-aeff-5b49f8392aea)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  However, I only see global shortcuts in System Preferences.  I don't see PowerPoint specific shortcuts listed there.  So how did you find the answer? Ppt help told me ⌘=

Comment: see my Edit how to see all PowerPoint specific shortcuts